# Google Page Speed Insights doesn't like my lazy loading hero banner

Tags: javascript, css, google-pagespeed

I have a giant hero banner on my front page, covering the whole screen, and the image lazy loads, so it's blank with a spinner showing until it fades in. The problem is Google Page Speed Insights mentions render-blocking CSS and prioritize visible content for this page. However, I get a 98/100 on the same website, but for a different page without the hero banner.

So, I think it's safe to say the image is causing an issue. When I look at the screen shot on the report, it just shows the blank white screen before the image has loaded in. I deliberately keep it blank like this until it's fully loaded and rendered, using JavaScript. Is there any way to improve my Page Speed score, despite this situation?

Comment: Don't worry so much about what Google says. If your page is loading fast enough, then it's a-ok.

Comment: Is there a real problem or do you just want to improve the score for the sake of improving the score?

Comment: Well, a better score is good for SEO isn't it?

Comment: I don't believe the lazy loading is the issue in regards to the score.  If it's saying that it's docking you for render blocking CSS then most likely it's not related to the lazy load but something else with the way you've deployed your stylesheet.  Check out [this link on CSS Render Blocking](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-blocking-css) from Google.  
Also, I'd like to suggest that you try out Chrome Canary.  They have recently implemented a new way to audit the site using Lighthouse amongst other new awesome features.

Answer (score 0):

Google page insight is rendering your initial html response without running your javascript or external css files. So all that it sees is your html and embedded styles.
It will show you the before and after of your page, and if too many pixels have changed in between it will reduce your score.

To solve that - don't lazy load anything above the fold.

I know many say "don't worry about google page speed insight score", but with this recommendation from google I agree- your page should render the above the fold content as fast as possible and defer items below the fold if necessary.

Comment: I disagree. Sometimes the top of the fold will look ugly without JavaScript manipulation. It's better to have the user wait a little bit in order to make a better first impression.

Comment: If your above the fold content is dependent on JavaScript manipulation you will not be able to render it quickly enough to get a high score with google anyway. In any case this is a specific case.

Comment: @TomerAlmog But won't not lazy loading it just make your page even slower, since the browser has to pull in the big image now before it can start rendering? It seems counter productive to make your page deliberately a little slower just to make Google _think_ it's actually faster.

Comment: I agree @Lawyerson, but google values fast initial rendering above the fold. I do agree that some things don't make sense, for example, loading and caching css in external file is better for the user, instead of loading it again with each page. But google will deduct points for that.